# JavaScript function alert box does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code in my JavaScript that will show an alert box.
The code works fine in Google Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
                                jAlert('You have already selected <?php echo $int; ?> theme.\nPlease deselect one of the themes to choose a new theme.', 'Number Of Theme Exceeded');
                        });
                        return false;
```

How can I go about changing it to allow it to work in Firefox?

Comment: put the code of your `jAlert` function.

Comment: You use this plugin, i guess? http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/

Comment: Does adding this helps: `$('body').jAlert(...`? As I see [here](http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/02/22/jalert-jquery-alert-box-plugin/)

Comment: why you are using `return false;` outside of your function?

Comment: if you are using a recent version of `firefox` you should be able to use the developer console. Hit `F12`. View the console and see if you are getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is very difficult to get the error. As I don't know the code of your `jAlert`. But there may be many reasons behind that.

**First:** Check your `jQuery` version and browser compatibility.

**Second:** Your browser version (Old/New)

And from your code One thing seems to be correct. You `return false;` outside of your function. Which should be like that-

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    jAlert('You have already selected <?php echo $int; ?> theme.\nPlease deselect one of the themes to choose a new theme.', 'Number Of Theme Exceeded');
//return false;
/*
 return false should be inside of some function. 
 If you are copy this code from somewhere then comment this line.
*/                 
});
```